# AS2 Attaching a Bitmap to Dynamic created Variables

Tags: dynamic, actionscript, bitmap

I'm stuck with this problem and simply cannot get it solved, sorry if there was another post about this already but I couldn't find it as well.

On to the problem then: I'm trying to make a simple function capable of initializing and updating bitmaps, and a few other variables I haven't thought of yet, when needed.

I created on the stage some MovieClips called slot0, slot1, slot2 etc... inside another MovieClip called ButtonRootPannel in order to have a visual of where I'll be putting the images without having to guess numbers in the code.

Together with those I set up this code:

```
var buttons_rootArray:Array = new Array;

for(var i=0;i<=11;i++){
    this["slot"+i] = this.ButtonRootPannel.createEmptyMovieClip("slot"+i, i);
    this["slot"+i].customState = "Inactive";    //Active, Inactive or Unavaiable
    this["slot"+i]._x = eval("_root.ButtonRootPannel.slot"+i)._x;
    this["slot"+i]._y = eval("_root.ButtonRootPannel.slot"+i)._y;
    this["slot"+i]._width = eval("_root.ButtonRootPannel.slot"+i)._width;
    this["slot"+i]._height = eval("_root.ButtonRootPannel.slot"+i)._height;
    buttons_rootArray.push(this["slot"+i]);
}

UpdateButtonsSlot(0,"BuildButton");
UpdateButtonsSlot(1,"CancelButton");

function UpdateButtonsSlot(slot:Number, newImage:String):Void{
    var tempData:BitmapData = BitmapData.loadBitmap(newImage);
    var tempClip:MovieClip = eval(buttons_rootArray[slot]);
    //buttons_rootArray[slot].unloadMovie();
    //buttons_rootArray[slot].clear();
    tempClip.attachBitmap(tempData,this.getNextHighestDepth(),"auto",true);
}
```

Anyone knows what I might be doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, problem solved, this now seems to be working for some strange reason:

```
for(var i=0;i<=11;i++){
    var currentMC = eval("_root.ButtonRootPannel.slot"+i);
    this["slot"+i] = this.ButtonRootPannel.createEmptyMovieClip("slot"+i, i);
    this["slot"+i].customState = "Inactive";    //Active, Inactive or Unavaiable
    this["slot"+i]._x = currentMC._x;
    this["slot"+i]._y = currentMC._y;
    //this["slot"+i]._width = currentMC._width;
    //this["slot"+i]._height = currentMC._height;
    buttons_rootArray.push(this["slot"+i]);
}
```

Only those commented lines makes the MovieClip disappear if I uncomment them. Will just leave them out then and problem solved.